# Single getData() represents which property in java

Tags: java

I have been asked in interview...
what is 
`void getData()` and `public void getData()`.
Is it data hiding or encapsulation. as i know class is encapsulation . can u please clear my understanding. I have read some online documents but they are saying making private variables is data hiding and change them through methods is encapsulation..

Comment: well one thing a `void` Getter method is: very confusing.

Comment: hey sorry .. lets say any return type.

Comment: Hi Got it thnx ..what i understtod is .. mainly abstraction is generalizing and encapsulation is method, and abstraction and encapsulation is inter-related to each other.